# Does using Elasticsearch as key value cache like redis makes sense

Tags: caching, elasticsearch, redis, multiprocessing

I have recently encountered a question that since redis is not distributed and don't support parallelism(multi-core), isn't elastic search be a better choice to use instead of redis for caching purpose.
This is all in reference to a simple web, where we used redis to cache db query.
I have kind of got the idea [here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Replacing-redis-with-elasticsearch-GET-query-speed-counters-and-lists-td3426738.html),
but still not sure whether it has any real benefits. Opening up this thread to discuss the advantages/disadvantages in doing so.

Comment: Should probably edit your question so that you aren't "opening up a discussion".

Answer (score 1):

It's not really what you asked for but you might want to have a look at [Aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com).

> Redis is an in-memory data structure store known for speed and often used as a cache. Both Redis and Aerospike are open source, however, when applications need persistence or when applications must scale but servers have maxed out of RAM, developers should consider Aerospike, a distributed key-value store that is just as fast or faster than Redis, but scales more simply and with the economics of flash/SSDs.

Comment: Just to complement the answer, this post compares Redis with Aerospike in detail: http://www.aerospike.com/when-to-use-aerospike-vs-redis